# Sharing Git Extensions scripts

Tags: git-extensions

We are a small software developer company changing our versioning system to Git, using GitExtensions.

The problem I'm looking for an answer to is how can we share the Git Extensions own scripts without having to copy the whole GitExtensions config file.

Thanks,
SanTa